# How to pass string from bash to python function

Tags: ssh, scripting, python3

I have a python function which takes a parameter as input and I want to automate and call it through bash. But bash is giving error when i pass variable(string) when calling it

```
a="test"
python -c "from pipeline_runs.z_full_pipeline import test; test($a)"
```

fails with

```
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

But the same runs when variable is int

```
a="10"
python -c "from pipeline_runs.z_full_pipeline import test; test($a)"
```

This runs while the first code fails. Can anyone explain why the behavior is so, and what should I change to pass string from bash script to python function

Comment: This question is really "how do I pass strings to a python program" (and it's not done the way you do it), and it's honestly a programming question. To make this really short: you want to use *command line arguments*, or passing in textual data through *standard input*. Both is well-documented for Python!

Comment: (and your error has nothing to do with passing strings from bash to python. You're just not passing a string, but a name. That's a lack of correct python and really has nothing to do with Linux/Unix)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I realise that I was passing a name instead of string. I thought bash had a specific way to pass string, which is why I thought it was a bash issue and did not realise it is a python issue. If you have more info on where I should check about passing string to python, that would be helpful.

Comment: as said, as command line argument or standard input. Both methods are documented on python.org's library documentation.

Comment: People: Please don't vote to migrate on topic questions. This is 100% on topic here and should not be migrated.

Comment: @terdon don't agree. "Why does my python not know a name I pass?" is not a UNIX/Linux question, but about what a string literal is in Python.

Comment: @MarcusMüller python is a standard tool used to administer *nix systems and this is not a question about string literals, it's about "how do I get my *nix system to work with this" and that is on topic.

Comment: @terdon I mean, you have some authority on what is on- and off-topic here, but this question really doesn't strike me as posed as intended, as also signified by ssuraj asking for guidance on where such documentation can be found! The problem also isn't caused by the passing, but by the lack of python string delimiter quotes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the main issue here is about the shell, python is incidental. The reason it doesn't work is because the variable is expanded by the shell before python ever sees it, so python ends up seeing an unquoted string literal. So it really is about how the shell and python interact. If this had been presented as a python script, that could arguably be off topic, but a one-liner is essentially a *nix command, so...

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, I have no more "authority" about what is on topic than anyone else. Mods don't decide that, the community does. Mods do tend to be very familiar with the scope, that much is true, but that doesn't mean I'm right just because I'm a mod!

Comment: Now we're getting into an interpretation about what OP's problem is: do they expect the variable to expand to something quoted? then, you'd be right and this would be about how variables get expanded in shell expansion. I'd say OP 1. simply overlooks the needs for quoting here, and knows how variables gets expanded by the shell, making this a pure python issue,and 2. is using a strange programming question in which they change the program instead of dealing with program input through one of the many ways that are well-defined (argv, argp, stdin…) and this is also a more general prorgamming …

Comment: …issue. :-) In both aspects, as far as I interpreted the question when I clicked on "this is a programming question that belongs on SO", this is programming and not related to the shell–python interaction, even if the title of the question says so. Your interpretation is applicable as well – it didn't occur to me – but that just means that you *should not* vote to migrate, right? Re: Authority: Didn't mean "authority to decide on your own" (bad choice of words on my end), I mean, you're kind of an "authority I'd usually ask" as a long-time observer, participant and thus cooperation-stylist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a shell function instead. Paste this into your terminal, or add to your shell's configuration files (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash)

```
pipeline_test(){
  python -c 'from sys import argv; from pipeline_runs.z_full_pipeline import test; test(argv[1])' "$@"
}
```

And then run as

```
pipeline_test "$a"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is the better method: while passing as environment variable like Frédéric does works, it's a bit strange to do it, when argument passing was literally invented to, and named after, passing string arguments to programs. It also has no side effects to processes spawned further down the line, so from a cleanliness aspect, I'd prefer this argument passing here to the environment-modification in Frédéric's answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```bash
export a="test"
python -c "from pipeline_runs.z_full_pipeline import test; test('$a')"
```

In this case, the command will be expanded to `from pipeline_runs.z_full_pipeline import test; test('test')`

And you will have `'test'` instead of `test`. The former is a string and the later is an undefined variable.

But a safe way to proceed is to use the `os.environ` dictionary. Then you put a script in a example.py file. And start with:

```py
import os
a = os.environ['a']
test(a)
```

This way is better scalable and you don't have to expand a string.

Note, in shell, `a="test"` and `a=test` are synonymous.

Comment: Thanks, the above one works but below one, using os module gives KeyError

Comment: Note that you need to `export a` for it to be available in `os.environ`.

Comment: I have forgotten to tell you to export the variable. `export a=test`.

Comment: Ah, that makes it work. Thank you

Comment: The first one would be an example of what **not** to do. Use `os.environ` or `sys.argv`, but don't embed the expansion of the variable in the code argument. That's a typical ACE vulnerability.